# Gremlin - find subgraph from specific starting points

Tags: database, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am having problems with creating quite a simple query:

Lets assume a graph with nodes representing people and edges of type 'has child'.

I get a subset of the people as starting point and I need to find all the descendants (recursively). More specifically, I am only interested in the edges:

Example:

```
a -> b -> c
d -> b
(starting points = [c]) => []
(starting points = [b]) => [b->c]
(starting points = [a,b,c]) => [a->b, b->c]
(starting points = [d]) => [d->b, b->c]
```

So far, I got to this query:

```
g.V().has('name', 'something'). // this line gets replaced by various filters
repeat(outE('child').dedup().inV()).
until(
    outE('child').count().is(eq(0))
).
path(). // get all paths
unfold(). // flatten the list of lists
filter(hasLabel('child')). // filter out only edges
dedup()
```

However this query does not work properly, if we select more starting points on the same path (an example can be selecting all vertices by doing g.V()....)

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to get back a deduplicated list of all the edges crossed between the start vertices until the leaf nodes are reached?

Comment: I added an answer based on that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get back a deduplicated list of all the edges crossed between the start vertices until the leaf nodes are reached, a query like this will work:

```java
g.V('start-id').
  repeat(outE('child').store('edges').inV()).
  until(not(out('child'))).
  cap('edges').
  unfold().
  dedup()
```

Comment: That looks promising! Thanks a lot.